# How to get complete data from kendo grind?

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid. Pagination is enabled. at any point ex : click on a button I can get only data which are displayed in current page from datasource.

How can get the complete data so that I can iterate and get specific row data? (the specific row may be in any page)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you add some more explanation?

Comment: Is this button(Which you want to click) in all rows and do you want the row information where button is clicked?